# Capistrano: Do not ask for password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I have a rails capistrano task that deploys code and works, however when it checks out the code from my server's git repo it asks for a password, twice, is there a way I can bypass this by putting the password in the capistrano script?  Code example is below...

```
set :repository, "ssh://gituser@example.com/opt/git/hub/app.git"
set :deploy_via, :copy
# server stuff unrelated..
  set :user, "deployer"
  set :password, "password"
```

I am using capistrano 2 btw.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ssh tools generally have your clients' backs, and never allow passwords on commandlines.

Look up "passwordless SSH". You will generate a public key and private code, ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and ~/.ssh/id_rsa. That's enough to get you Googling; you will upload the key & code to your server, then upload the key to your GIT repository (following its owners' instructions.)